24.04 upgrade issues
Machine Dell OptiPlex 9020
Updated to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS ~ Noble
Prior to latest upgrade this message appeared in dropdown box in centre top of screen ~"Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool or your package manager."Computer generally very slow to open docs & load apps etc

Which version did you upgrade from?

To re-enable third party sources like PPAs, open software and sources, have a look at the disabled ppas, and add them again from terminal

We need more information to fix the slowness issue. Do you have a dedicated graphics card? What are the system specs?

Upgraded from 22.04.0 LTS

Now sound from all sources, even test buttons in Audio test, is garbled

The upgrade path from 22.04 to 24.04 has not opened yet. How did you upgrade? Please fresh install ubuntu 24.04

Upgrade offered in dropdown box & I followed prompts & installed upgrade
